# Android resource linking failed error i got in android studio while building the App . I don't know how fix this issue . I am new to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, build-error

[1]this is the screenshot of output and error i got .

[1]: image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2kUz.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is occurring because you are using color values which you haven't defined. You have to define color values in `colors.xml` for those colors which you are using for your theme.

Like for black color `<color name="Black">#000000</color>`

Answer (score 0):

Add all color values you are using in your project in your colors.xml and colors.xml(night), as you are using dayNight theme and error, will go